# UI of the application changed afyer generating report from lighthouse

Tags: javascript, testing, mern, lighthouse

I have made an MERN application. Then I tested that application using lighthouse from chrome. After generating report, my application's UI got changed. I don't know why it's not showing my UI as before even after reloading page, restarting server and also restart the laptop.
The login page had 3 input bar and were at right side and a photo at left. After generating the report, the UI changed to all elements stretched out. Each element's width is as big as viewport width.

This happened in branch_eg1. In master branch it wasn't like that. It was all good as before. But when I pulled the code and merged with master branch, then same behaviour happened with master branch.

Please help me to look out of this.

Comment: lighthouse cannot change your site, so the issue is most likely your browser has some cached files that influence the layout (as lighthouse will run a mobile test so perhaps some mobile styles are being cached). Go to the application tab in developer tools (F12) and clear everything for the site, cookies, sessions, app cache if used, service workers etc. Go to the network tab in developer tools and select "disable cache", then reload the page.

Comment: Cleared all cache from cookies, session, etc. Also disabled cache in network. No change

Comment: And does the problem persist in a different browser? As if it does then the problem was the reverse (you had some styles cached that lighthouse somehow cleared and those are now missing from the page when it is served from the server)

Comment: It is same in other browsers too.

Comment: The style for input bar is 400px, but it's showing big as the screen width. In inspect element, it is written 400px, but it's showing full only

Comment: I also tried to host that application and see if is this any change in code or what. When i hosted on netlify, the build folder, It is changed... Means the issue is there. That means it has done something with the code. But not getting it where?

Comment: check that you aren't getting a 404 for one of your CSS files or check that your CSS files don't contain an error. My guess is you had a cached file that was correct and Lighthouse cleared it and you now have either a missing file or a file with a missing curly brace or similar error, unfortunately without a URL to test against this is the most help we can offer.

Comment: I checked all the CSS files. All are good. Also I tried to revert my git commit of 2 days before i tried light house. The issue is the same. Code got reverted, but same issue in UI

Comment: As I said unfortunately there is nothing we can do to help now and you will have to solve this yourself, there is nothing for us to test against and you have a nearly impossible scenario (an external program changing your website). The issues is caused by something else and is just a coincidence. If you want to share a URL or create a fiddle with the problem we can try to help but as it stands I am voting to close the question. Hope you get it sorted.